# Run jqwik tests with Jupiter console launcher

Tags: java, junit5, junit-runner, jqwik

For testing purposes (no pun intended) I run some tests outside the IDE or MAven using the Console Launcher that comes with JUnit Jupiter. It finds all the JUnit 4 (aka. Vintage) and JUnit 5 (aka. Jupiter) tests.

However, it does not discover my [jqwik](http://jqwik.net/) tests.

What I tried: In a Maven project, invoken `mvn test-compile dependency:copy-dependencies`, then in the target folder:

```
java -jar …/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.2.0.jar -cp classes -cp test-classes -cp $(echo dependencies/* | tr ' ' :) -p example
```

This incantation will run Jupiter and Vintage, but not jqwik, while the Surefire run does.

Comment: Are you sure it's on the classpath? Could you please provide a minimal sample project?

Comment: The extremely astute reader (that is: not myself) might have noticed the type in my command line: Maven puts the dependencies in the `dependency` folder. Therefore, my classpath foo did not work. “Unfortunately”, almost everything worked without the path set.

You were right: The path did not include the engine. Case closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine, if done correctly (user error on my side). To use the console launches in *any* project (well, Maven project (well, single-module Maven project)), you can use the following incantations:

```bash
mvn clean test-compile dependency:copy-dependencies
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.2.0.jar \
        -cp target/classes -cp target/test-classes \
        -cp $(echo target/dependency/* | tr ' ' :) \
        --scan-class-path target/test-classes
```

Instead of the final `--scan-class-path` option you may wish to use other selectors like `-p` for a certain package; or add `-e jqwik` to choose *only* the jqwik tests.